# How to get the int value from my Model enum when I have an record instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I convert a Model enum to the INT value?

I am trying to do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum user_type: [:member, :super]
end
```

Now say I have a user record, now I want to use the `user_type` enum value in another query:

```
u = User.find_by_type(@user.user_type)

def self.find_by_user_type(user_type)
  User.where(user_type: user_type).take
end
```

This doesn't work because the **user.user_type is returning "member" or "super"** and I need 0 or 1.

**Is there a way to get the Int value from my @user instance?**

(Rails 4.x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get integer equivalent of enum type:

```
User.user_types[self.user_type] # returns integer value
```

Replace `self` with another user instance if necessary.